# How to automate Eclipse Plugin versioning?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We have 20 plugin in our project. After each build we have to update our plugin version from ´Manifest.mf´ file.

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
```

For example after an update I have to manually update this line and give a new number? How can I automate this for 20 plug-ins?

I see that at Eclipse plug-ins there is 3.3.1.v20150403-1352. How do they achieve this? How we can have such a versioning system. Such as major version, then minor version then date of the build and the hour.

Any ideas are welcome.

At the moment we thought to write a plugin view where we can manually update these lines by entering from a main view. But even what we thought as a solution is not easy. There should be a tidy way to do the versioning, but how?

Is it done through PDE API & Build?

I found these links:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-api-tools/
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering

Here it states:

> "In Eclipse, version numbers are composed of four (4) segments: 3 integers and a string respectively named major.minor.service.qualifier."

This is given automatically when the plugin is created and how can I have Eclipse PDE update this automatically when I change a code in plugin?

In the IBM link it says that Eclipse gives you error when you need to change the `@since` tag and manifest file. Any help is appreciated regarding this topic.

Comment: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.basebuilder.git/plain/readme.html Check this link too.

Answer (score 3):

The major, minor and micro values are generally just set 'by hand'.

When the qualifier value is specified as 'qualifier' it is substituted by the build system with the actual qualifier. The default for this is the date and time ('YYYYMMDDHHMM'). This can be overridden using a 'forceContextQualifier' property (exactly how you do this depends on which build system you are using).

More details in the help [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_version_qualifiers.htm)

Comment: Can't we update major minor and micro values by Eclipse PDE API Tools. What is the state of art for other eclipse plugins ? How people manage their plugins ? How do they version so many plugins ? seting 'by hand' is error prone. We forget to update the version numbers of plugins. There should be a hint to do these things ? I have tried Eclipse PDE API Baseline, I set the baseline for 3 plugin projects. Then I modified the source code to add a new method but It didnt give an error to update the version of the plugin via manifest file. Any Idea ?

Comment: The Eclipse wiki entry on [Version Numbering](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering) doesn't mention much in the way of tools apart from something used with Maven/Tycho builds which I don't know about.

Comment: Don't you think Eclipse PDE API Tools can help ? At the versioning link at the end of the document it says there is API Baseline in API Tools. Is it not the solution ? Also there is a link : http://web.archive.org/web/20130903064936/http://eclipse-tips.com/tutorials/26-api-tooling-tutorial

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for the links, that qualifier is very handy, actually